# How xamarin compiled to android?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, compilation

I want to know how xamarin c# is compiled to run on android.

I read that it runs on mono.

1. Since which version android run mono?
2. how much is mono slower than running on dalvik when writing application with java?
3. What is the advantage writting on c# than java?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your deleted q answer is here: [link]https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w

Answer (score 2):

C# is compiled to IL and packaged with MonoVM + JIT’ing. The application runs side-by-side with Java/ART (Android runtime) and interacts with the native types via JNI. This is how it is run.

Answer (score 1):

So the normal build process goes like this.

- First the C# (or other .NET code) is compiled into **DLLs**, then an **ACW**(Android Callable Wrappers) is created, that provides the interface into the managed runtime. Mono libraries are also taken, and these are all placed into an APK.
- When you unzip this APK package you will find `classes.dex` file which contains `MainActivity.java` file which is used to initialize the **mono runtime** and start the app.
- Here the purpose of [mono runtime](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/) is to run ECMA CIL byte codes into native code. ECMA CIL byte codes is what .NET code is compiled into. The mono runtime allows this compiled .NET code, to run on different platforms and architectures, such as Android and iOS.

To know more about this there is a very comprehensive article by Adam Pedley. [Here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-android-aot-works/)